# updating the checkout comment from a payment controller in opencart

Tags: php, checkout, opencart

how do I update a Checkout comment from a payment controller in opencart. Or is there a way to set it if its not already set? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the value to

```
$this->session->data['comment']
```

Simple as that. You could of course check if its empty first, and append a value if required